# Python/Django: Upload an image to media root itself without creating a folder in it

Tags: python, django

I need to put all my uploaded images in the MEDIA_ROOT directory itself without creating a new folder in it. Following is my model.py:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(_('Upload Image'), upload_to="/media")
```

But is shows an error 
    "SuspiciousOperation: Attempted access to '/media/image.jpg' denied". Can anyone suggest a proper method to make it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove leading slash from `upload_to` argument:

```
# upload_to="/media"
upload_to="media"
```

or use `MEDIA_ROOT` as path:

```
upload_to=MEDIA_ROOT
```

Comment: It will create a directory named 'media' inside my MEDIA_ROOT. My requirement is to upload images to the MEDIA_ROOT directory itself and it shouldn't create any sub directory within it.